# Can \usepackage{color} and \input tikz work together in Plain TeX/eplain?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, plain-tex

I use Plain TeX and Eplain. In my document I'm using both the `color` and `url` packages inside the `\beginpackages..\endpackages` block. Just now I tried adding `\input tikz.tex` (as the TikZ manual states) to the document and got the error:

```
Package pgfbase: Error! Unsupported color model `'. Sorry.
```

over and over. The document's colors were all wrong (indeed, they were gone) and the document looked terrible.

I figured that the `color` package somehow conflicted so I removed that and disabled the hyperlinks I was using which automatically introduce color.

Is there any way to get the `color` package with Eplain and TikZ to play nicely together? I'd rather not disable hyperlinks.

Edited to add:

Here's a sample input file, as requested.

```
\input eplain
\beginpackages
  \usepackage{url}
  \usepackage{color}
\endpackages
\enablehyperlinks
\hlopts{}

\input tikz


\definexref{anchor}{display}{type} Hi there. This refers to the \ref{anchor}.

\bye
```

This file will produce the warning above and also produce odd-looking PDF output. Without the `\input tikz` it should look normal.

Comment: It's hard to tell without at least a small example of code.

Comment: @egreg, added one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the colors after loading `tikz`; moreover use the following pattern:

```
\input eplain
\beginpackages
  \usepackage{url}
  \usepackage{color}
\endpackages

\input tikz

\enablehyperlinks
\definecolor{urlcolor}{rgb}{.2,.4,.6}
\hlopts{colormodel=,color=urlcolor}

\definexref{anchor}{display}{type} Hi there. This refers to the \ref{anchor}.

\bye
```

Using

```
\hlopts{colormodel=rgb,color={.2,.4,.6}}
```

(that according to the docs should work) breaks `tikz`. Remember that `tikz` supports only the rgb and gray color models.

Comment: Thanks, @egreg, this works great! How could I have figured out the solution to this problem? I don't know much about colors; maybe I should start there.

Comment: @D.Bueno I just tried to figure out what was happening and the usual strategy of moving things around.