# tikz and colorboxes in plain tex

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I recently discovered that I could use `tikz` in my plain tex documents using `\input tikz`. I'm happy with it and began to experiment the drawing of some pictures. But, when trying to compile some documents, I discovered that all the `\colorbox` were now fill with black. The following example gives a black rectangle instead of a gray one with "some text" written in it :

```
\input eplain

\beginpackages\usepackage{color}\endpackages

\input tikz

\colorbox{gray}{some text}

\bye
```

Is this a known problem ? Is there a way to get back `\colorbox` working properly with `tikz` ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: I guess the answer here might help you:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42958/can-usepackagecolor-and-input-tikz-work-together-in-plain-tex-eplain

Comment: Thanks for your help. I saw this answer befor posting my own question. I don't use the url package and all colors I use are rgb or gray. In fact, `tikz` does work correctly, but it breaks the `\colorbox` that become all black.

Comment: I'm not answering your question again, but if you just want to have the colored text you can use just tikz and forget about loading color.tex. With tikz only you use: \color{gray}{some text}

Comment: Of course I understand that I can replace `\colorbox` with `tikz` pictures, but I don't know how to do for now. As I'm a complete novice in `tikz` I which I could stick with my old macros for a while and then introduce `tikz` as soon as I can do it.

Comment: The replacement is easy: instead of using \colorbox{gray}{some text} you write \color{gray}{some text}. Doing it this way requires only tikz, so you can remove the `color` package.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to avoid the conflict, so that you can keep using the color package (since you didn't like my suggestion of using only tikz and using \color{}{} instead of \colorbox{}{})

Simply load it with the "xdvi" option like this: `\usepackage[xdvi]{color}`

I'm not sure why using the xdvi option "fixes" the problem. I stopped investigating the theoretical reasons after discovering this workaround :-)

```
\input eplain

\beginpackages\usepackage[xdvi]{color}\endpackages

\input tikz

\colorbox{gray}{some text}

% if not loading color package and using only tikz use this
%\color{gray}{some text}

\bye
```